Studying more than one sampling unit in a single randomization
So we have a list of organizations that dedicate themselves to a certain social service.
Our goal is to ask both laborers and customers an overlapping(but not fully) set of questions for each one of them.
As we have a big list of organizations and each one of them can have a different(according to theory) population of customers we decided to first stratify and then conglomerate on each organization.
The problem is then the need to further stratify on both laborers and customers, to make two randomizations of conglomerates(two studies, one for laborers, one for customers), or maybe using only one randomization and then sampling each unit separately, so as to reduce the number of organizations to visit to save time and costs. Do you think thesd methods are feasable?
Thanks
